# generate unique Number from string

Tags: javascript, optimization

**Backstory**

I'm working on a small interactive piece and need a way to uniquely keep track of object names using only integers. I thought I had a solution but once I fix a collision I seem to get into another.

example of object names:

`/=====Folders=====/MAZE/Grid Spawner/Cell ((0, 0))/Room (0, 0)/Level 0, Drawer/drawer_0` where all the `0` values can be anything from 1-10

**Question**

How can I make sure that any entry I come across can turn into a unique integer?

**Code**

```js
let arr = [
"/=====Folders=====/MAZE/Grid Spawner/Cell ((0, 0))/Room (0, 0)/Level 0, Drawer/drawer_1",
"/=====Folders=====/MAZE/Grid Spawner/Cell ((0, 1))/Room (0, 0)/Level 0, Drawer/drawer_1",
"/=====Folders=====/MAZE/Grid Spawner/Cell ((0, 2))/Room (0, 0)/Level 0, Drawer/drawer_2",
"/=====Folders=====/MAZE/Grid Spawner/Cell ((0, 0))/Room (0, 3)/Level 0, Drawer/drawer_1",
"/=====Folders=====/MAZE/Grid Spawner/Cell ((0, 0))/Room (0, 0)/Level 0, Drawer/drawer_3",
"/=====Folders=====/MAZE/Grid Spawner/Cell ((0, 3))/Room (0, 0)/Level 0, Drawer/drawer_2"];

function GameObjectPathToInt(str) {
  let ret = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) 
  {
    let posVal = 1 + i;
    let charVal = 1 + str.charCodeAt(i);
    ret += posVal * charVal;
    /* console.log(charVal, str[i]) */
  }
  
  return ret;
}

arr = arr.map((str) => GameObjectPathToInt(str));
/* console.log(arr.sort()); */
arr.reduce((prev, cur) => {prev == cur ? console.log("DUPLICATE", cur) : null; return cur});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

** EDIT **

I must add that I am passing this integer value to a backend service which limits my integers to a uint32 max value of 4294967295 (0xFFFFFFFF)

Comment: Are there every duplicate strings with the same numbers in the same position?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming those numbers in the string are what makes it unique, why not extract that info from the string?

```
const GameObjectPathToInt = (string) => {
    var matches = string.matchAll(/\d+/g);
    return parseInt("1" + [...matches].join("")) // 1 prevents leading 0 being stripped
}
```

Likely the reason your original plan doesn't work is the number could be equivalent if you swap some characters around. You attempt to handle it I think but still whilst `i` increases, `charCode` could decrease and end up clashing.

You might be able to get it working by concatenating a number as a string then converting it like above. That way you make it order-derived.

You could also consider using SHA1 and then converting the resulting hexadecimal to a number.

Comment: I made a mistake here, fixing

Comment: Ok should be ok now, wasn't matching all numbers previously.

Comment: I added a limitation to my question - your rather clever answer still fits within the limitation but unfortunately there will be some strings that have no numbers in them that will not have any numbers in them.

Comment: Is it the case some numbers will be "blank" and some will be filled in one single stream? I think this could be tackled. Let me know, I'll edit it.

Comment: @Jacksonkr If you could add an example of one of these strings it would help

Comment: I must have been revising my original sentence and between little sleep (new baby) and multitasking I was a bit too incoherent. I meant to say there will be some paths without digits eg "/a/b/c" and "/c/b/a" so they will be different objects but have a similar condensed value of "0" or whatever null is made to be. I had an idea of stripping everything unimportant from the path to get a starting string like "///01/00/3/" but I'm starting to think I may run into a similar issue and really need to rethink the core of multiplayer state management all together.

Comment: Yeh my first though was, "what is the number used for". You could just, on the back end, have a unique identifier against these states -- in the back end store. Which is just autogenerated much like any DBMS tech. Hell you could just use UUID and send that over in the string. Do you have an idea about every possible string between the `/`? It might suck, but if they were known to the front end you could map each of them an int.

Answer (score 1):

If strict uniqueness and inversion is not needed, maybe utilizing an existing hashing algorithm is a better choice than inventing something new.

If not, then a simple way may be constructing a `BigInt` with each 16 bits representing an character (suitable with only [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane) characters; if characters like emojis exist in paths, consider giving 21 bits for each character or using [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set_characters#Surrogates)):

```js
let str = "/=====Folders=====/MAZE/Grid Spawner/Cell ((0, 0))/Room (0, 0)/Level 0, Drawer/drawer_1";

let id = 0n;
for (let ch of str) {
  id <<= 16n;
  id |= BigInt(ch.charCodeAt(0)); // will only get the first surrogate for special chars
}
console.log(id.toString());
```

Comment: I added a limitation to my question - while this answer provides a unique value for each object the integer size becomes too big for my situation.

Comment: @Jacksonkr are strict uniqueness and *inversion* needed? If just serving as identifiers, then it's a common practice to use the hash number (like CRC-32 or a 32-bit slice of SHA, but a full digest is better) of the object name, or more commonly, its content.

Comment: by inversion do you mean something like decoding the int? If so then this only needs to be converted one way and not back. I was originally looking at using something like md5 as security doesn't matter but I found myself converting from 128 bit down to 32bit which opens up plenty of potentially for duplicate ID's.